# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on an mp4 file I've added to project

Tags: swiftui, avkit

I'm unable to figure out why I'm getting this "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error when the file is clearly in the project and is an mp4 file. I've imported the proper AVKit, etc. and still cannot figure this out

[image]

```
 @State var player = AVPlayer(url:  Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bump", withExtension: "mp4")!)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

I've even replaced the player with the following code and have gotten the same result

```
AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bump", ofType: "mp4")!))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check to make sure `bump.mp4` was added into bundle resources.

> Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> Tap (+)

[image]

Comment: face palming myself because this was the problem, thank you!

Comment: No worries, take it easy.